# Build from terminal fails

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I'm trying to build a native android application, when compiling it using AndroidStudio it works but when compiling it from a terminal with the command:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable do incremental execution: full task run
:app:packageMyAppDebug FAILED
:app:packageMyAppDebug (Thread[Task worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.466 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageMyAppDebug'.
> class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageMyAppDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zfile.ZFiles.apk(ZFiles.java:128)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.<init>(ApkZFileCreator.java:93)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zfile.ApkZFileCreatorFactory.make(ApkZFileCreatorFactory.java:50)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.<init>(IncrementalPackager.java:130)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.createPackager(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:510)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:461)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:321)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.doFullTaskAction(PackageApplication.java:75)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 20 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.592 secs
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'll use the `assebleDebug` gradle command in my CI pipeline.

Comment: Try to use: ./gradlew clean ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace to get more log. Then paste the log in here.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxxVmKn-ehyhN0d2YTRaZXNmMUE/view?usp=sharing) the complete output for the ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace command

Comment: I can't download it. Can you take a screenshot or send it to my email: frank@simicart.com, please?  And a question, Do you have a google-service.json file in your project?

Comment: I sent you the file by mail.
yes, I have a google-service.json for each flavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally **solved** by removing `bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar` from

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\lib\ext
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\ext
```

after that I have deleted all the content of

```
C:\Users\myUser\.gradle
```

now `./gradle assembleDebug` work like a charm